# ESlint: How to ignore Parsing error: Invalid regular expression flag

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, eslint

I'm creating a Chrome extension. I want to write a code that matches strings including `\n` like this:

```
var s = "a\nb";
console.log(s.match(/a.*b/s)); // prints non-null
```

I used the [`s` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) because it worked on Chrome 67.0.3396.99. However, this flag is not defined in standard Javascript, so ESlint says

```
2:22  error  Parsing error: Invalid regular expression flag
```

Is there any way to ignore this? I tried `// eslint-disable-line no-invalid-regexp` in my code and

```
"no-invalid-regexp": ["error", { "allowConstructorFlags": ["s"] }],
```

in my .eslintrc.json but neither worked (it seems it works only for `RegExp` constructors and not `//` regexp).

I tried `// eslint-disable-line` and `/* eslint-disable */` but neither worked, too.

In [The ESlint document](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments),

> Note: Comments that disable warnings for a portion of a file tell ESLint not to report rule violations for the disabled code. ESLint still parses the entire file, however, so disabled code still needs to be syntactically valid JavaScript.

So this `s` flag is considered as invalid Javascript. **Is it really impossible to ignore this error?** Or can this be ignored by plugins or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how your code is structured, you might simply be able to write an alternate regex such as :

```
console.log(s.match(/a[.\s]*b/));
```

this would match an 'a', followed by one or many characters matched by the dot OR a space character, followed by a 'b'.

This would remove completely the warning since you would not be using the 's' flag anymore.

On the other hand, the 's' flag appears to be an [EcmaScript 2018 feature](http://2ality.com/2017/07/regexp-dotall-flag.html), so maybe simply passing the parameter [ecmaVersion](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) with the value '2018' when launching eslint.